# Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" for tag fragment

Tags: android, xml

Trying to make some changes in XML file and new problem fired up:

Her's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        map:id="@+id/map"
        map:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        map:layout_width="wrap_content"
        map:layout_height="250dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Got error at

```
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

**Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" for tag fragment**

Comment: But if both namespaces are same, why you want to declare it again?
`xmlns:android` and `xmlns:android', both are referring same namespace `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I'm helpful here but i only declare the Namespace once in my case in the RelativeLayout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <fragment class="com.blablabla.MyFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I dont declare the namespace again in the fragment as shown above. As far as I know the Namespace only has te be declared once in the parent ViewGroup

Comment: Yes, but it concerns same namespaces. 
I have no idea why, but ur soultion removes error. Checking

Comment: Ok, let me know if this fixed your problem. I'm curious since I'm nog 100% sure.

Comment: Nice to know! I guess that a ViewGroup (with its childs) can only have one namespace. So declaring it twice will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, you are most likely running into [this bug in the build tools](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53283).

Comment: So there's no way to achieve that - Map and e.g TextView in the same activity?

Comment: If there's a bug how the hell app named "Endomondo sports tracker" using maps and other stuff on same activity?

Comment: @krzakov: "So there's no way to achieve that - Map and e.g TextView in the same activity?" -- sure. Just don't use `xmlns:map`, setting the values in Java instead. "If there's a bug how the hell app named "Endomondo sports tracker" using maps and other stuff on same activity?" -- perhaps they have developers that use less profanity.