# Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm getting an error:

Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment

for lines

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

in

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >
        <TabWidget
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        />
         <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
         >
         <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:name="com.example.storeitemfinder.ItemListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
         </FrameLayout>
        </TabHost>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916638/unexpected-namespace-prefix-xmlns-found-for-tag-linearlayout)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

for fragment in xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html

The root element can be either a ViewGroup, a View, or a  element, but there must be only one root element and it must contain the xmlns:android attribute with the android namespace as shown.

To make sure i just went through the below posts that are similar

[Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" for tag fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511605/unexpected-namespace-prefix-xmlns-for-tag-fragment)

[Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916638/unexpected-namespace-prefix-xmlns-found-for-tag-linearlayout)

[Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952259/unexpected-namespace-prefix-xmlns-found-for-tag-listview)

Edit:

From the link you posted in your comment it looks like you are looking for is tabs with fragments. So try the below and modify according to your requirements.

Example :

I have set min sdk is 11

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
        tabA.setText("Tab A");
        tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentA>(this, "Tag A", MyFragmentA.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tabA);

        Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab();
        tabB.setText("Tab B");
        tabB.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentB>(this, "Tag B", MyFragmentB.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tabB);

        Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab();
        tabC.setText("Tab C");
        tabC.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentC>(this, "Tag C", MyFragmentC.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tabC);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int savedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("SAVED_INDEX");
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedIndex);
        }

    }

 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putInt("SAVED_INDEX", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
 }

 public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> 
     implements ActionBar.TabListener{

        private final Activity myActivity;
        private final String myTag;
        private final Class<T> myClass;

        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> cls) {
            myActivity = activity;
            myTag = tag;
            myClass = cls;
        }

  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

   Fragment myFragment = myActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myTag);

   // Check if the fragment is already initialized
         if (myFragment == null) {
             // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
             myFragment = Fragment.instantiate(myActivity, myClass.getName());
             ft.add(android.R.id.content, myFragment, myTag);
         } else {
             // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
             ft.attach(myFragment);
         }

  }

  @Override
  public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

   Fragment myFragment = myActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myTag);

   if (myFragment != null) {
             // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
             ft.detach(myFragment);
         }

  }

  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

    }
}
```

Framgent A

```
public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment {

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
  return myFragmentView;
 }

}
```

Fragment B

```
public class MyFragmentB extends Fragment {

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
  return myFragmentView;
 }

}
```

Fragment C

```
public class MyFragmentC extends Fragment {

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);
  return myFragmentView;
 }

}
```

fragment A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment A" />
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment b xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment B" />
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment c xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment C" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: thanks, but that just removes those two errors and gives me three more:

error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix for fragment

Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

for the last two :(

Comment: 1) error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix for <fragment 



and

2) Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix for 

tools:context=".ItemListActivity"

and


    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

Comment: @user2749364 remove this tools:context=".ItemListActivity" and tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" /

Comment: hrm... that seemed to remove the errors, but when i run the program on my phone i still only have 1 tab!

Comment: @user2749364 you need to have tabs. you do not have one.

Comment: well i was trying to make my app have two tabs -_-

basically i was trying to embed the master-flow default template into one tab, and then create a second tab for another activity

Comment: I was trying to follow this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android

and frankenstein that code into something that could hold my master-flow code in one tab .  could you help me do that please?  i've been stuck on this for hours :-/

Comment: He needs to *add* something, not keep removing things. You seem to be just guessing.

Comment: well when i run that code it is error free.. so thanks for that.  but it's basically a default masterflow template

Comment: oh maybe it's because i'm missing a linear layout chunk below my fragment and before the end of framelayout

Comment: @user2749364 check the example here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Comment: @user2749364 removing those lines in fragment is right i guess. but your need to add tabs to the tab host. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android. check the java code and the xml in the same link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `xmlns=` schema attribute on the document element, and probably an `xmlns:xsi` attribute as well, for example:

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

[This is from a web.xml, the `xmlns` here doesn't apply to your namespace.]

Comment: how do i do that?  where do i put it?

Comment: @EJP but those lines  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools should be there only for root element i guess. Having those lines is a problem?

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. You need an "xmlns=" attribute as well. The attributes you mention can be anywhere.

Comment: @EJP i tried it as you said but it does give error as op stated. i wonder if its android specific http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html. I also searched on stackvoerflow and some say it should be for the root element only.

Comment: @EJP and also this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html. quoting from docs The root element can be either a ViewGroup, a View, or a <merge> element, **but there must be only one root element and it must contain the xmlns:android attribute with the android namespace as shown**.

Comment: I haven't said otherwise. I've said something else, and I *specifically* said 'as well'. Don't try to manufacture a disagreement about something I haven't even said.

Comment: @EJP i am not disagreeing i am just merely quoting it from the docs. You don't need those two line i asked op to remove fro fragment element. It is necessary fro the root element. the root element must have xmlnx:android attribute with android name space. Also the examples in the docs don't have those for child elements. Tell me if i am wrong. if i am wrong i will make a correction and makes sure i learn from my mistakes

Comment: I haven't said you're wrong here. I haven't said anything about it at all. You are arguing to no purpose. Or are you discussing your *own* answer here, rather than mine? If so, you are doing it in the wrong place. This part is supposed to be for comments on *my* answer.

Answer (score 0):

In you tabhost layout file, change the parent TabHost Tag code as below

```
 <TabHost   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        >
```

xmlns declarations have to be first and then it has to be used. as far as I am concern defining xmlns second time in the layout file doesn't affect or create error but I hope you are facing problem due to wrong declaration

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be applicable to your specific problem.  I ran into the same issue.
Eclipse at times can be rather fussy.
What I did was:
Backed up the original file.  Then did a copy paste back into the code that was causing the error.
Recompiled and the error was gone.